# Bootstrap Image/button/image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button between two images, I would like to center the button to the image height. Could someone help me please?

```
  <div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-xs-4 imgwifi">
      <img src="imagenes/example1.png" class="img-responsive center-block imgwifi" alt="Cinque Terre"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 boton  pagination-centered">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onClick="CheckLoginCode()">Entrar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 imgvm">
      <img src="imagenes/example2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block imgvm" alt="Cinque Terre"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By "center the button to the image height" I take it you mean that you wish to center vertically? If so, you can use this CSS:

```
.boton {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```